# Python, using data from .dat file

Tags: python, input

I'm new to Python, this problem is pretty basic, still I couldnt find the right solution.

So, I copied a basic program called "bigdigits.py", which was suggested in a python learning textbook, the code you can see below, and figured out how it works. I have a "name.dat" file with one line  of numbers, e.g. 12340987 in the same folder as the program file.

The question is: how do I implement this file so that this line of numbers is used as an input data for my code and in the end I get an answer in big digits? All suggestions are very appreciated.

```
import sys

Zero  = [" *** ", 
         "*   *", 
         "*   *", 
         "*   *",
         "*   *",
         "*   *",
         " *** "]
One   = [" * ",
         "** ",
         " * ",
         " * ",
         " * ",
         " * ",
         "***"]
Two   = [" *** ",
         "*   *",
         "*  * ",
         "  *  ",
         " *   ",
         "*    ",
         "*****"]
Three = [" *** ",
         "*   *",
         "    *",
         "  ** ",
         "    *",
         "*   *",
         " *** "]
Four  = ["    * ",
         "   ** ",
         "  * * ",
         " *  * ",
         "******",
         "    * ",
         "    * "]
Five  = ["*****",
         "*    ",
         "*    ",
         " *** ",
         "    *",
         "*   *",
         " *** "]
Six   = [" *** ",
         "*   *",
         "*    ",
         "**** ",
         "*   *",
         "*   *",
         " *** "]
Seven = ["*****",
         "    *",
         "   * ",
         "  *  ",
         " *   ",
         "*    ",
         "*    "]
Eight = [" *** ",
         "*   *",
         "*   *",
         " *** ",
         "*   *",
         "*   *",
         " *** "]
Nine  = [" ****",
         "*   *",
         "*   *",
         " ****",
         "    *",
         "    *",
         " *** "]

Digits = [Zero, One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine]

try:
    digits = sys.argv[1]
    row = 0
    while row < 7:
        line = ""
        column = 0
        while column < len(digits):
            number = int(digits[column])
            digit = Digits[number]
            line += digit[row].replace('*', digits[column]) + " "
            column += 1
        print(line)
        row += 1
except IndexError:
    print("Usage: bigdigits.py <numbers>")
except ValueError as err:
    print(err, "in", digits)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Letters Made From Letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43893431/letters-made-from-letters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the first question I'd ask is, have you understood this code?

If yes, what you basically need to do now, is look at what you're doing whenever you want to print a set of bigdigits for a number, and try to reverse the process, to read the numbers from a file instead:

```
digits = [None]*10
with open('digits.dat') as fd:
  for line in fd:
    for i in range(10):
        digits[i].append(line[i*5: i*5 + 5])
        # assuming each digit is of width 5, and no space between digits
```

Now, you'll have created the `digits` object using the `.dat` file, and can go ahead from there.